# UIAlertView query. Returning to where the UIAlertView was called within a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am trying to use an `UIAlertView` within a loop and respond to the choice made at that time within the loop. This does not happen as is demonstrated by the following test code:

```
- (IBAction)testAction:(id)sender {

for(loop=0; loop<5; loop++)
{
NSLog(@"Loop: %d", loop);

if (loop==1)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d?", loop]  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"0" otherButtonTitles:@"1", nil];
    [alert setTag:1];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"Pressed: %d", alertPressed);
}
if (loop==4)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d?", loop]  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"3" otherButtonTitles:@"4", nil];
    [alert setTag:2];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"Pressed: %d", alertPressed);
}
}
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView.tag == 1)
{
    alertPressed=buttonIndex;
}
if (alertView.tag == 2)
{
    alertPressed=buttonIndex+2;
}
```

}

The log looks like this:

```
alerttest[893:18299] Loop: 0
alerttest[893:18299] Loop: 1
alerttest[893:18299] Pressed: 0
alerttest[893:18299] Loop: 2
alerttest[893:18299] Loop: 3
alerttest[893:18299] Loop: 4
alerttest[893:18299] Pressed: 0
```

The loop runs to its completion before the alert is shown on the screen, and it clearly doesn't post the value of **alertPressed** since the it doesn't return to where the `UIAlertView` was called at runtime. While this test has helped me understand what is actually happening is there a solution to this?

Comment: You have to refactor your code to deal with an event driven model. `UIAlertView` doesn't block the running code so you can't use a simple loop.

Comment: So I guess there is no way of making the UIAlert to stop the rest of the code running?

Comment: In other words: if your loop never ends the user will never see the alert. [alert show] doesn't actually show the alert, it just tells the framework to show the alert as soon as possible, which is never if you don't return from your current method. The UI thread mustn't be held up anywhere.

Comment: The loop ends. What I mean is I want the alert to show during the loop, for the code to wait until the alert is responded to and then to continue back from where the alert was called, reacting to what was chosen at the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest refactoring your code to properly leverage the event system if you're trying to get user responses. However, you could change your code to do this (if you really want to):

```
- (IBAction)testAction:(id)sender {

  for(; loop<5; loop++)
  {
    NSLog(@"Loop: %d", loop);

    if (loop==1)
    {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d?", loop]  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"0" otherButtonTitles:@"1", nil];
      [alert setTag:1];
      [alert show];
      break;
    }
    if (loop==4)
    {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d?", loop]  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"3" otherButtonTitles:@"4", nil];
      [alert setTag:2];
      [alert show];
      break;
    }
  }
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (alertView.tag == 1)
  {
    alertPressed=buttonIndex;
    NSLog(@"Pressed: %d", alertPressed);
    loop++;
    [self testAction:nil];
  }
  if (alertView.tag == 2)
  {
    alertPressed=buttonIndex+2;
    NSLog(@"Pressed: %d", alertPressed);
    loop=0;
    [self testAction:nil];
  }
}
```